# Querydsl logging queries with bindings

Tags: oracle, logging, binding, configuration, querydsl

logQuery is called in prepareStatementAndSetParameters mehtod - SQLInsertClause class

```
   protected void logQuery(Logger logger, String queryString, Collection<Object> parameters) {
        String normalizedQuery = queryString.replace('\n', ' ');
        MDC.put(QueryBase.MDC_QUERY, normalizedQuery);
        MDC.put(QueryBase.MDC_PARAMETERS, String.valueOf(parameters));
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug(normalizedQuery);
        }
    }
```

how can I set debug level to logger ?

Answer (score 0):

That `logger` there is from SLF4J API. Depending on the logger you have behind the API you use facilities of that underlying logging implementation.

For instance we use Logback Classic (dependency `ch.qos.logback:logback-classic`) and I can explicitly override what configuration file to use with `-Dlogback.configurationFile=devel-logback.xml` in JVM parameters. Default mechanism is documented [here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html). My file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %level [%.60thread] %logger{1} %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.JPAQuery" level="DEBUG"/>
    <!-- more loggers -->

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Also adding `-Dlogback.debug=true` to JVM arguments adds some debug output when logback is being initialized.